# font madness on linux desktop

Tags: debian, fonts, desktop, editors, word-processing

I am using Debian 10. `fc-list` shows following fonts installed on my system:

```
$ fc-list | cut -d':' -f2 | sort -u
Bitstream Charter
Century Schoolbook L
Courier 10 Pitch
DejaVu Sans
DejaVu Sans Mono
DejaVu Serif
Dingbats
Inconsolata
Inconsolata for Powerline
Nimbus Mono L
Nimbus Roman No9 L
Nimbus Sans L
Standard Symbols L
URW Bookman L
URW Chancery L
URW Gothic L
URW Palladio L
```

and here is the selection of fonts I see available in my document editor `Abiword`:

[image]

Most of the idiotic fonts displayed seem to have been installed via package `gsfonts`:

```
# fc-list | grep gsfonts | cut -d':' -f2 | sort -u
Century Schoolbook L
Dingbats
Nimbus Mono L
Nimbus Roman No9 L
Nimbus Sans L
Standard Symbols L
URW Bookman L
URW Chancery L
URW Gothic L
URW Palladio L
```

`gsfonts` was installed as a dependency for several packages (`abiword`, `gnumeric`, `libmagickcore-6.q16-6`) so I cannot remove this package.

**Is there a way to hide these useless fonts from the font selection in my editor? (or globally for all applications)**

I am sure I will never need `Dingbats` or `URW Chancery L` fonts when writing letters in my editor. The long list of available fonts only confuses me, every time I have to look for the 2 or 3 fonts that are actually useful. It steals few seconds of my life each time I have to sort through the list.

Also, a side-question, the drop-down list shown in the screenshot of `Abiword` shows 3 generic fonts that are not listed by `fc-list`: `Monospace`, `Sans`, `Serif`. Where do these come from? Are these hardcoded in `Abiword` ? Or are these just aliases pointing to the specific fonts?

Lastly, does anybody really need `Dingbats` font (perhaps for displaying `pdfs` ?)
Or is it installed by `gsfonts` only to increase the bloat?

Comment: Dingbats is a standard postscript font

Comment: As you surmise, Dingbats is part of [the standard PDF fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Others), and it is in practice used quite a lot. Ghostscript provides Dingbats and the URW fonts to meet the requirements of [the PostScript Level 2 core font set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#PostScript_Level_2).